# is the time of computer and localhost same?

Tags: php, web, time, localhost

I have a xampp in my computer. When I try to echo in my php files like:

```
$time=strtotime("now");
echo $time;
```

It gets me diffrent time than my computer's time. The time echo gives me is about two hours earlier than my computer's time.

How can I fix the time of my local server.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a timezone set in your php.ini file? Look for `date.timezone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php: "Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default time zone."

Probably a timezone problem, see above link for complete documentation.